# Can I Install a generator inlet box inside my garage?

Tags: wiring, generator

I am installing a generator inlet box and want to install inside of my garage.  Is there a reason why I cannot.  Can only see them installed outside. I am installing a interlock switch.

Comment: Think it is more a placement of the generator.  To keep people from running a generator inside of their garage.

Comment: Carbon monoxide, carbon monoxide, and carbon monoxide, in that order...

Answer (score 2):

### Running a generator in a garage is suicide. Don't *invite* it.

The most recent hurricane notwithstanding, the #1 killer of people in hurricanes is, astonishingly, stupid generator accidents. Almost all of these are *carbon monoxide poisoning* **which kills the whole family**.  And guess what the most common blunder is there?  **Putting the generator in the garage**.

Of course this is where you swear on a stack of bibles that "Oh no, of course you will put the generator outside and slip the cord through a cracked-open door".    And guess the #1 way that carbon monoxide makes it into a home: through a cracked-open door, inevitably cracked to let a cord through.

Having the inlet inside the garage is only setting the stage for somebody else to do something suicidal in the future. I don't think an AHJ would approve it.

### Try building an enclosure some distance from the house.

Of course the #1 reason people want to do that is concerns of generator theft.  Since best advice is to have the generator *at least* 10 feet from the house in any case...

My best advice is to build a secure and well-ventilated "dog house" or shed a good distance from the house, and then lay underground conduit to carry both the generator feed and any incidental power in the building. (though if it were me, I would install a tiny solar/battery system in there for lights, that would work during the power outage! If that removes need for a 120V circuit out there, all the better.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* but you'll need a safe way to run the generator cord from the generator, outside and a safe distance from your home, to the inlet inside the garage.  You probably won't want to leave the garage door open, because that will admit CO and expose your garage to (probably) the storm you are dealing with.  And you'll need a very long, heavy, expensive cord.  And if it's running through your garage you will probably end up driving on your expensive cord.

People install inlets outside to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in a previous home, installed the genset inlet in the garage and ran it outside along the edge of the garage door, eliminating the risks associated with driving over it. Most garage doors have enough tolerance that they can be closed with a small obstruction such as a generator cable.  But if it's easy to install outside, that's also a good idea, just make sure it's well protected from the weather. Both approaches are code legal.